# Is "ignorably" a word?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-word, programming

I would like to use *ignorably* as the adverb of *ignorable* but I am not sure whether this is correct. I did not find *ignorably* in any online dictionary.

To give the context: Normally, you cannot ignore a thrown exception in programming: You are forced to handle it if you want to make you program work correctly. I have a method that does something similar to throwing an exception but you are not forced to handle it immediately. So my question is whether the following sentence is possible: *An exception was thrown ignorably.*

Comment: What is the context? Chances are you are looking for a completely different word in the first place.

Comment: Although something might be *ignorable* I can't think how one might **do** something *ignorably*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Normally, you cannot ignore a thrown exception in programming: You are forced to handle it if you want to make you program work correctly. I have a method that does something similar to throwing an exception but you are not forced to handle it immediately, so the question is whether I can name it as  _ThrowExceptionIgnorably_.

Comment: In that case you are not looking for an English word, but for a variable name. That is expressly off-topic here. Precisely because as far as the English language is concerned, you can name it absolutely anything you want.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I am looking for an English word because I want to build up my symbol names out of correct English words.

Comment: `ThrowIgnorableException` might do, then.

Comment: @Andrew You are right. The reason why I wanted to use _ignorably_ over _ignorable_ is that it would underline that nothing has changed with the exception object itself (it has exactly the same type, property values etc.) but with the process of throwing and handling it compared to _ThrowException_.

Comment: I think the question is completely within scope. It is a question about usage. The word is not (easily) found in dictionaries, but I have found examples of it used in scholarly articles in computer science journals, and I would like to address the question. It not only has a straightforward answer, it also raises interesting and instructive issues about what makes a word "a word," i.e., how new words enter the language and become "legitimate."

Comment: “An exception was thrown ignorably” sounds perfectly fine to me, and means exactly what you are looking for: that the exception itself is not necessarily ignorable, but the _way in which the exception was thrown_ can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the word would be clear but it is completely nonstandard. If I saw a method named "ThrowExceptionIgnorably" during a code review I would probably call it out and ask the programmer to change the name. But if they insisted I would let it slide.

Alternatives:

- ThrowIgnoredException
- ThrowUncaughtException
- RethrowException